# Delphi android hotfix 2017

Tags: delphi

I have just downloaded the hotfix from embarcadero website and I have read that it's mostly about Android issues. I am going to install it in my computer but my company has bought new computers and we need to install Delphi on them.

We are going to download the official Delphi Tokyo `iso` from the website and it's fine. But now the question: do we still have to download and apply the hotfix? Or they have already included the hotfix in the iso?

Comment: We don't know which ISO you're downloading. Embarcadero's website has tons of downloads. What does the download link say? What date was it published? Dated before or after the hotfix?

Comment: I am going to use this link: http://altd.embarcadero.com/download/radstudio/10.2/delphicbuilder10_2.iso

Comment: But in fact I am asking this question because I don't know the date and I am not sure if this is the latest download link. Does the latest download link already include the hotfix?

Comment: Embarcadero has NOT released an updated ISO that includes any of the recent hotfixes.  Generally, the installers are not updated with hotfixes until full Updates are released, so you will likely have to wait until 10.2 Update 1.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ok thank you. Was the 10.2 Update 1 just an example or it is really going to happen? You should make an answer btw

Comment: @EmmaRossignoli: Tokyo 10.2.1 is in the works (it is more than just fixes, it will bring Linux to C++Builder, etc), but is not released yet, and no ETA announced yet.

Comment: Ask. The. Vendor.

Comment: the hotfix is not working, so better to not install it. If you plan to develop under android or ios, you must avoid tokyo and stay with Berlin. https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17162